# Create a list using another list

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a list from a file by using `.split()` method, now I want to loop over this list to get certain strings from it to another empty list. when I use `.append()` method it copies the entire list with the brackets to the new list which is not what I want. how do I solve this?
this is the code I use:

```
file_name= input("Enter file name: ")
name= open(file_name)
for word in name:
    word=fh.read()
    line=word.rstrip()
    word=line.split()
    for words in word:
        lst=list()
        if word not in lst:
        lst.append(word)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

```
def fuse(k,n):
  k = (5,3,n)
  n = []
  for i in k:
    n.append(i)
  return n
print(fuse([5,3],[3,6]))
```

If you entered `([5,3],[3,6])` as the arguments to fuse, you would get `[5,3,[3,6]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay more attention to your indentation and variable naming.
I think the following is what you tried.

```
file_name= input("Enter file name: ")
filtered_words = list()
# Open the file with the help of a context manager, which closes the file 
# again in the event of an error.    
with open(filename) as fd: 
    # Iterate over all lines of the file.
    for line in fd:
        # Cut off the white space at the end of the line and split the line 
        # into tokens, using space as a separator.
        words = line.rstrip().split()
        # Iterate over all tokens.
        for word in words:
            if word not in filtered_words:
                # Append the token to the new list if it doesn't already exist.
                filtered_words.append(word) 
print(filtered_words)
```

If you want to remove all duplicate values, I recommend using a
[`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)

lst=[]
#looping over words in the file
for word in fh:
    words=word.split()
#looping through the words in the list
    for words in words:
        if words not in last:
        #append words to the new list
            lst.append(words)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```